# Question about the convergence of a power series

Tags: complex-analysis

In Rudin's Real Complex analysis, the following is claimed:

Let $\{c_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of complex numbers. Let $r>0$ be a positive number, and $a$ be a complex number. If $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n(z-a)^n\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)$$ is convergent for every $z\in B_r(a)$, then:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nc_n(z-a)^{n-1}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(2)$$ is convergent for every $z\in B_r(a)$.

The argument of the book is:

Since the series in (1) converges for every $z\in B_r(a)$, the root ratio test shows that the series in (2) converges for every $z\in B_r(a)$.

This argument does not make sense to me. If the series in (!) converges for every $z\in B_r(a)$, why must $\lim\,sup_{n\rightarrow \infty}|nc_n(z-a)^n|^{\frac{1}{n}}$ be less than $1$ for every $z\in B_r(a)$

My guess is that there is some sort of converse for the root test, which I don't know about and the book is using it implicitly in its argument.

Thank you

Comment: $n^{\frac{1}{n}}\rightarrow 1$ when $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: @user48805 I realize that, but then what ?

Comment: @user48805 I believe your strategy would work if we knew that $\lim\,sup_{n\rightarrow\infty}|c_n(z-a)^n|^{\frac{1}{n}}<1$, but why must this be true

Comment: For any $\epsilon>0$, when $n$ is large enough, you will have $|nc_n(z-a)^n|^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq (1+\epsilon)|c_n(z-a)^n|^{\frac{1}{n}}$.

Comment: @user48805 and what would that lead to ? (Thanks for your help btw)

Comment: Well, that would lead to the same inequality with a $\limsup$ in front of both terms. Then you can take $\epsilon$ to $0$ and you have your result.

Comment: @user48805 I agree from the beginning that $\lim\,sup_{n\rightarrow \infty} |nc_n(z-a)^n|^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq \lim\,sup_{n\rightarrow \infty} |c_n(z-a)^n|^{\frac{1}{n}}$. But this does not does not lead to the convergence of series (2). Because we don't know that the RHS of the previous inequaliy is less than $1$

Comment: @user48805 Thanks . I gave myself some time and thought about it again and understood it, my mind was just tricking me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z \in B_r(a)\setminus \{a\}$. Let further $\rho := \dfrac{r + \lvert z-a\rvert}{2}$. Then $0 < \lvert z-a\rvert < \rho < r$, and $$\zeta := a + \frac{\rho}{\lvert z-a\rvert}(z-a) \in B_r(a)$$ with $\lvert \zeta - a\rvert = \rho$.

By assumption, the series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n (\zeta-a)^n$$

converges, hence the terms are bounded,

$$\lvert c_n\rvert\cdot \rho^n \leqslant M$$

for all $n$. Hence we have

$$\left\lvert c_n(z-a)^n\right\rvert^{1/n} = \lvert c_n\rvert^{1/n} \lvert z-a\rvert \leqslant \left(\lvert c_n\rvert^{1/n}\rho\right)\cdot \left(\frac{\lvert z-a\rvert}{\rho}\right) \leqslant M^{1/n}\cdot\frac{\lvert z-a\rvert}{\rho},$$

for $n \geqslant 1$, and therefore

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \left\lvert c_n(z-a)^n\right\rvert^{1/n} \leqslant \lim_{n\to\infty} M^{1/n} \cdot \frac{\lvert z-a\rvert}{\rho} = \frac{\lvert z-a\rvert}{\rho} < 1.$$

Thus, we also have

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \left\lvert n c_n (z-a)^n\right\rvert^{1/n} \leqslant \lim_{n\to\infty} n^{1/n} \cdot \lim_{n\to\infty} M^{1/n}\cdot \frac{\lvert z-a\rvert}{\rho} = \frac{\lvert z-a\rvert}{\rho} < 1.$$

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I gave myself some time ,thought about it again and understood it, my mind was just tricking me